# What are the optimum hyperparameters for ResNet50 (v1.5) with ImageNet 2012 dataset?

Tags: pytorch, resnet, imagenet

What are the optimum hyperparameter settings (loss function, learning rate, data augmentation, learning rate scheduler, etc.) to achieve >75% accuracy with ImageNet50 (2012) dataset using ResNet50? I have tried the suggested parameters from [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/DeepLearningExamples/blob/master/PyTorch/Classification/ConvNets/resnet50v1.5/README.md), but my accuracy is nowhere near 75% (it's below 30%) after 90 epochs. What I am missing?

currently, I am using the following settings-

```
import torch
import torchvision

batch_size = 256
epoch_n = 90 #number of epochs

#training data transformer for data augmentation
train_transform= torchvision.transforms.Compose([
    transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224),
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
]) 

#loss function, optimizer, and learning rate scheduler
criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(label_smoothing=0.1)
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=batch_size/1000, momentum=0.875, weight_decay=1/32768)
lr_scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.CosineAnnealingLR(optimizer, T_max=epoch_n)
```

Comment: I would suggest you to start with torchvision's training scripts. You can find it [here](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/tree/main/references/classification)